# DNS record for thousand domains

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record, configuration

I'm working at a small webhosting company. I have to set up the autoconfig (Thunderbird) and autodicover (Outlook) files, so that user (who have their own domain names, like www.userxyz.com) could set up their Email account in Outlook or Thunderbird by just providing their username and password.

I've followed [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration#DNS) instruction (for Thunderbird). I've managed to build the .xml files, and everything works fine, but at the point (which I have linked to) where it says I have to set up a DNS CNAME record for every domain, I have a logic thinking problem.

We have many customers, everyone with another domain name. I can't set up a `autoconfig IN CNAME autoconfig.userXYZ.com` CNAME Record for every customer we have. This would be not efficient. So my question is how could I handle that, or how would be that handled? I don't have a glue how I could ask that question in another way, but I hope someone understands it.

The user types in his Email adress (into Thunderbird), like `office@userXYZ.com`. Thundbird is looking at `autoconfig.userXYZ.com/mail/config-1.1.xml` if there is a config file. So I have to bring Thunderbird to look to another adress, like `autoconfig.hoster.com/mail/config-1.1.xml`, so that I just have to manage one config file, and not thousands of them.

Sidenote: We are using BIND (9).

Thanks in advance.
Regards, john.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up the CNAME/A record, or the autoconfig files?

Comment: 1. You should specify Exchange Server in your question and your tags. 2. Exchange hosting companies don't usually manage DNS for their customers so they don't have to manage, and aren't responsible for, thousands of DNS records for the domains that they're hosting email for. The customer is usually responsible for getting the appropriate DNS records set up at their DNS host.

Comment: sorry for the weak problem explanation. i know how to set up a CNAME record, i know how to configure the config-files. but i don't know how i should set up a CNAME record for thousand domains! i would require weeks to get this done... so is there a way to set up a CNAME record for more than one domain, or is this impossible?

Comment: Why do you think it's different for a thousand domains than it is for one? Scripting editing of SOA records is trivial - but you don't even mention what DNS server you use. Are you really an ISP?

Comment: Why do you need to set up DNS records for thousands of domains? Do you or your company have thousands of domain names registered?

Comment: Please take a few minutes, review the comments (and [this helpful guide to asking good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)) and edit your question so it's sensible, clear, and explains what you're trying to accomplish and the infrastructure you have to work with.  Then let me know and I'll re-open it for you :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 I have rewrote the question, please reopen it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the server you would be using, but in BIND, inside named.conf, you can specify a file for each zone. If your environment is homogeneous, it gives you the ability to create a simple zone file. Inside that file you add the standard pieces, NS, A MX and CNAME records, and at the bottom, create the entry for the autoconfig.

You then use that single zone file for thousands of simple domains.

Of course, there are probably a million other ways to do so, but this is the one I have used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I had a thinking barrier, and now I know what to do with your comment. Yes we use BIND :)

Comment: Cool, hope it helps.